# Django: Model attribute looks for field works in view, but not in template

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-model-field

Say I have a model:

```py
from django.db import models

class Foo(models.Model)
    fav_color = models.CharField(max_length=250, help_text="What's your fav color?")

print(Foo.fav_color.field.help_text)  # prints: What's your fav color?
```

Say I have a view with context:

```py
{
    'Foo': Foo
}
```

And in a template `{{ Foo.fav_color.field.help_text }}`, the result will be blank. However `{{ Foo }}` will print the string representation of the model, so I know the models is getting passed into the template.

Why are the attributes look ups to get the `help_text` failing in the template, why is the `help_text` empty in the template?

Comment: can you share your view? Why do need to show the help text in the way you are sharing?

Comment: @ruddra There is no view associated with this code, its actually a custom rendered template, with a context, that is rendered before run time.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the template engine is considering `Foo.fav_color` as a string instead of model field.

When you pass the `Foo` model to the template, the string representation of the model that includes its class name and primary key value is automatically generated by Django. So, the moment you do `{{ Foo }}`, Django displays string representation of the `Foo` object, which is different from accessing the `fav_color` field.

#### Solution:

You can directly pass `help_text` in template so:

```py
{
    'fav_help_text': Foo.fav_color.field.help_text
}
```

Then, access `help_text` in template only through `{{fav_help_text}}`

#### Edit

> There is no view associated with this code, its actually a custom rendered template, with a context, that is rendered before run time.

You can define a [`context processor`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors) to include the `Foo` model instance in the context of every request so:

```py
from myapp_name.models import Foo

def foo_context_processor(request):
    return {'Foo': Foo}
```

Then add this to `TEMPLATES` in settings.py so:

```py
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        # ......
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                # ......
                'myapp.context_processors.foo_context_processor',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Now, With this context processor, the `Foo` model instance will be included in the context of every request, then simply do the following in template:

```html
{{ Foo.fav_color.field.help_text }}
```

Comment: `{ 'fav_color_help_text': Foo.fav_color.field.help_text }` makes more sense. But since I have multiple parameters, and I wished to pass just the model, instead of manually building a dict for the context

Comment: @run_the_race As stated, I think you can't do it with model name.

Comment: @run_the_race See the edited answer, it may help you.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, but I don't wish to pollute the context with these values, that's not scalable architectural design. See the template tag I made below, cheers

Answer (score 0):

In the end I just circummed and created a custom template tag:

```py
register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def get_help_text(model, field_name):
    return model._meta.get_field(field_name).help_text
```

In template:

```py
{% get_help_text Foo 'fav_color' %}
```